# Safari Web Extension - injecting script only when extension button is clicked

Tags: javascript, swift, safari-extension, manifest.json, sfsafariviewcontroller

To keep it simple, I am taking reference for SeaCreator extension example from Apple.

You can take it from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1loBDgkJAEtyh0QehOUlgOSyUnW9ZZDk6/view?usp=sharing

In this example as mentioned, *we are replacing fish names with different emojis*.

The thing is when we tap on the extension icon, it turns into blue to indicate the extension is active and whenever any page is rendered, all fish names will be automatically replaced with emojis.

See screenshot -> [image]

What I need is I don't want to keep the extension active always and I want the replace action to be executed only when I press the extension button. So, whenever I open a new webpage I must have to press extension toolbar button only then replacement should be done.

In the code I have attached, I did try few things but none help.

```
//browser.runtime.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
//function handleMessage(msgEvent) {
//    alert('message received');
    var wordReplacementMap = {"Fish": "", "Shark": "", "Squid": "", "Whale": ""};
    for (var wordToReplace in wordReplacementMap) {
        replace(document.body, wordToReplace, wordReplacementMap[wordToReplace]);
    }
//}

//chrome.runtime.sendMessage("message");
```

I am always facing -> undefined `browser` or undefined `chrome`.

In my original extension project I have used node modules and AJAX also so there are lots of dependencies why I did took reference for Apple's example.

The main thing is I want to turn off automatic script injection and only execute my script code when user taps on extension button. I don't need popup - just execution on tap of button.

Please let me know if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh that's so weird. I got it so late that, I have to include `background` script key in manifest.json besides 'content_script' key.

```
"background" : {
    "scripts" : [
      "bundle.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
      "js": [ "init.bundled.js" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
  }]
```

I already have `chrome.browserAction.onClicked...` method written inside `bundle.js` which is being called everytime I press extension button from Safari toolbar.

Whew.

Comment: It would be great if you can support me, I am looking for 2 weeks for getting the password input field on any web page that is load. Can you please support me here?

Comment: What's your question? However, I am iOS native developer and working on extension was just for a week's deed for me which was already pre-built and I just made few changes in it. Would you elaborate your question? If it's more related to Web, I would be wrong person to address that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Paresh

My requirement is as below:
verify current page is login page is not, currently I have done by checking input type password exist in the current page or not. 
Eventually all working well, but after 4-5 refresh suddenly it wont work.